# How to parse filepath with boost?

Tags: c++, boost

I use boost::program_options and boost::filesystem. I need to parse command line arguments.

```
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
   //command line arguments
     variables_map vm;
     try{
    options_description desc{ "Program usage " };
    desc.add_options()
        ("help,h", "Show help")
        ("input,I", value<std::string>(), "Input directory")
        ("output,O", value<std::string>(), "Output  file ");


    store(parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
    notify(vm);
```

How i can work with arguments as filepathes?

```
path file_path = vm.count["input"];
path file_path = vm.count["input"].as<std::string>();
```

Don't working

Comment: Besides the syntax error using two assignment operators, what problems do you have with the code you show? You *did* try it, didn't you?

Comment: It might be helpful to specify `using namespace boost::program_options;` in your code. Also, `desc()` requires round brackets, and not curly ones.

Comment: In the code only one assigment.I don't know how to get the value of vm.count["input"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the value of the path provided in the command line with `--input` to `file_path` with:

```
if (vm.count("input")) { 
   std::string my_path = vm["input"].as<std::string>();
   boost::filesystem::path file_path (my_path);
   std::cout << "The input path is: " << file_path << std::endl;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Error: type name is not allowed. <std::string>

Comment: @MikeVasilenko Please check if the revised version works. On my computer it yields the correct output.